# Finding coefficient of exponent in an expression

Tags: coefficients

I am trying to find coefficient of an exponent term in an expression. For example, consider

```
tt = E^(I*T0*(ω+σ));
```

Doing

```
Coefficient[tt, E^(I*T0*(ω+σ))]
(* 1 *)
```

gives 1. However,

```
Coefficient[tt, E^(I*T0*ω)]
(* 0 *)
```

this returns 0. How do I obtain $e^{i*T0*\sigma}$ as output instead of $0$?

I thought `PowerExpand` will work, but it also did not. I couldn't find the command to expand exponents.

PS: The expression `tt` is just a dummy expression, my original expression is really big and contains a lot of terms.

Comment: `tt / E^(I*T0*ω)`?

Comment: Actually the expression is really big, it contains a lot of other terms. That's why this method won't work. I'll add it in the question, thanks for the heads up

Comment: The issue is that, from a math pov, the problem is simply ill-defined. It is meaningless to state that the coefficient of $f(t)$ in an arbitrary expression $F(t)$ is $g(t)$. You can do that, canonically, if (say) $F$ is a polynomial and $f$ a monomial (and $g$ is just a constant). But, in more general terms, the problem is not well-posed (e.g. you can always introduce factors of $1=f(t)/f(t)$ everywhere, which changes the putative $g(t)$). You will have to be *much* more explicit in what $F$ is, and what are your rules, if you want the problem to be solvable. Only then can MMA try to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for a lot of cases:

```
Coefficient[Expand[tt] /. E^(I*T0*(ω + x_.) + y_.) -> U * E^(I*T0*x + y), U]
(*    E^(I*T0*σ)    *)
```

If `U` happens to be a symbol that you use somewhere else in the code, then just use some different symbol here instead of `U`.

**Updated version:** Thanks to @AccidentalFourierTransform for pointing out that localizing `U` is required.

```
getcoeff[t_] := Module[{U},
  Coefficient[Expand[t] /. 
    E^(a_.*(b_.*ω + x_.) + y_.) /; a*b == I*T0 -> U*E^(a*x + y),
    U]]
```

This also works with cases like

```
getcoeff[E^(1/2*I*T0*(2ω+6))]
(*    E^(3*I*T0)    *)
```

Comment: You could `Block` the variable `U` just to be sure.

Comment: Is `_.`a new feature in MMA12?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann no, [`Default`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Default.html) has been around since version 1. See [this tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OptionalAndDefaultArguments.html).